# Customize autofill for textboxes in google chrome using JSP or javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a textbox which takes input for an answer to a security question. When I come back to that page some other time, the autofill feature of google chrome or other such browsers prompts me with the previous inputs to that textbox, which I want to disable. I would like to do this using either JSP or javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HTML5 and this is in a `<form>`, you can look up the `autocomplete="off"` attribute for the entire `<form>` or specific `<input />`. It will disable modern browsers from filling in information.